# Difference between the two words: "satisfactory" and "satisfiable"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-meaning

Is there any difference between the two words - *satisfactory* and *satisfiable*? From Merriam-Webster,

[satisfactory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/satisfactory): giving satisfaction

[satisfiable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/satisfiable): capable of being satisfied

There is no example sentence or phrase for *satisfiable* in Merriam-Webster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"He had a satisfiable urge for ice cream.", indicating that he wanted ice cream and would be able to get some.

"The ice cream he had was satisfactory.", indicating that the ice cream he ate pleased him in the way that he expected.

The words, except for them both having "satisfaction" as a root, aren't very close in meaning.